# Is it possible to call an Azure function from Azure Workbooks?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm designing a data visualisation tool, and would like to call an API (the Azure functions) for that.

I'm looking up the Azure workbook documentation, but there's no mention of that. Is it possible to call a function/API from Azure Workbooks?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

!! Disclaimer, I have not tested this, only going by documentation.

### Custom Endpoint Support

Workbooks support getting data from any external source. If your data lives outside Azure, you can bring it to workbooks by using this data source type.  I don't see why an Azure Function endpoint would be any different.

To make a query control that uses this data source, use the **Data source** dropdown and select **Custom Endpoint**. Provide the appropriate parameters, such as **Http method**, **url**, **headers**, **url parameters**, and **body**. Make sure your data source **supports CORS**. Otherwise, the request will fail.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-data-sources#custom-endpoint